# How to fix 'Input string was not in a correct format.' when using TimeSpan.ToString()?

Tags: c#, time, tostring, timespan

I have a program that manages clients arrival, and whenever a new client is created, the `TimeSpan` property `TimeOfArrival` is assigned the current time of day with :

```cs
TimeSpan TimeOfArrival = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
```

Now I'm trying to put that in a more convenient format that way :

```cs
string ShortTime = TimeOfArrival.ToString("hh:mm");
```

Though now I get the following exception :

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

I can't seem to understand what the problem is. I checked and TimeOfArrival actually has a correct TimeSpan value right before I get the exception. That exception wouldn't surprise me if I was trying to parse an user input into a TimeSpan, but there I'm confused. Could anyone help ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You're super close.

Simply change to the string format being passed in to:

```
string ShortTime = TimeOfArrival.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
```

See [TimeSpan.ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_TimeSpan_ToString_System_String_) for more examples.

> That exception wouldn't surprise me if I was trying to parse an user
>   input into a TimeSpan, but there I'm confused.

So the thing being parsed and is not in the correct format is the string being passed to ToString(); there is nothing wrong with TimeOfArrival at all.

Comment: Thank you, indeed that was close.
Funny I've been looking for the answer for hours though I haven't come upon  any of the duplicates pointed above nor the msdn reference for TimeSpan.ToString(), guess I'm tired ;)

Comment: It happens, my friend.  Glad you've got an answer and can sleep tonight.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

As seen in [MSDN's Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_TimeSpan_ToString_System_String_) , the format should be of the form:

`@"hh\:mm"`.

`"h'h 'm'm"` should work as well.